# CSS prefixes for different browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

We all know that CSS prefix for Mozilla (Gecko), when we refer that property using DOM, is `Moz`. For example : `MozTransform`.

I have a list of prefixes used in CSS for different browsers, but I also want to know the prefixes used when referring them using DOM.

List of CSS prefixes:

```
-moz-
-webkit-
-apple-
-o-
-xv-
-ms-
-mso-
-atsc-
-wap-
-khtml-
-prince-
-ah-
-hp-
-ro-
-rim-
-tc-
```

Comment: Aren't they all just camel case?

Comment: I think the same, but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spec says that any letter after a hyphen should be capitalised. So -o- becomes O, -moz-  becomes Moz.

Internet Explorer doesn't follow spec: -ms- stays as ms. Webkit hedges its bet and goes with webkit and Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

Opera's is an **uppercase** 'O' for style.property in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/21 from Modernizr library.